# Remove Markdown tags from string

Tags: c#, xml, string, markdown, text-manipulation

I have a string which has Markdown tags embedded inside it.  I do not want to encode the Markdown as anything else, I just want to rip out all of the tags.

How can I do this quickly?  I need to do this as part of a batch processing job which processes around 5 million pieces of text, so speed is very important.

I looked at MarkdownSharp, and using `Transform`, but I'm not sure it's the best way of doing this.  I just want plaintext output, with no tags inside.  I'm even considering a regex removal, but I'm not sure what the most performant option would be.

Comment: You seem to have a few working options on your mind. Why don't you test them if one fits your need?

Comment: I was hoping someone with more in depth knowledge of the options might be able to chime in and help me out.  There are more options than what I have listed, so I mean I could also process it as XML and apply XSLT to it.  There are so many options, I can't try them all :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use MarkdownSharp or any other similar library (I recommend [Strike](https://github.com/SimonCropp/Strike), since it is surprisingly fast!) to convert the Markdown to Html and then use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to extract the text.

A faster option, but more work for you, would be to modify an existing Markdown parser to produce plain text instead.

Comment: Hey - Thanks for the link to Strike.  They linked to MarkdownDeep (something I've used in the past), and it appears as though they now support a plaintext output!!! :D

Comment: Really? I didn't know that! :-) Good to hear. Strike is surprisingly fast btw. It is really just a wrapper for a Javascript library so I would expect it to be slow, but it isn't...

Comment: It's not as fast as MarkdownDeep though... ;)

Comment: To expand on @Faraday's comment, in order to render the markdown as plain text, set the `SummaryLength` property of your Markdown deep instance to `-1`. To expand and @Faraday's comment: http://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/posts/49-MarkdownDeep-Plain-Text-Rendering

Comment: Is there any solution/plugin for flutter mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was a bit hard to get from the comments, but this works for .NET 6:

1. Install [Markdown Deep](https://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/) from NuGet. I needed something for .NET 6 so I used the Core version https://www.nuget.org/packages/MarkdownDeep.NET.Core/
2. Create a `Markdown` object:

```cs
using MarkdownDeep;
var markdownRemover = new Markdown()
{
    SummaryLength = -1
};
```

3. Strip the markdown from the text:

```cs
var plainText = markdownRemover.Transform(mdText);
```